# Using ImageMagick in Command Line in Android

Tags: android, shell, command-line, imagemagick

I have a rooted android device and I want to run the imagemagick library commands on android command line - Example, when I run this command in Windows command line "adb shell convert /sdcard/rose.jpg /sdcard/rose.png" it should convert the file to png. Is this possible? I looked at https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick but these look lie they can be used as libraries for my app and not directly? Is there a way of doing this or simply some other way of doing command line image manipulation in android which I can invoke from Windows?

Comment: Did you _install_ ImageMagick on the Android device? Maybe it’s just a matter of finding out the $PATH. (Does ImageMagick even exist for Android? If not, look at netpnm, it can do similar things.)

Comment: I could no find a way to install imgmagick - only libraries. I'll look at netpnm. Thanks!